# How to change display language on monaco editor

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

don`t know how to change display language from javascript to such as swift(or something else)

I installed using "npm install monaco-editor" command

```
    <script src="node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
    var editor;
    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' 
    }});
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {

        editor = 
    monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: [
                'function x() {',
                '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
                '}'
            ].join('\n'),
            language: 'javascript',
            theme: "vs-dark"
        });
    });


    function showMessage() {
        var text = editor.getValue();
        monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(editor.getModel(), "swift")
        editor.updateOptions({
            language: "objective-c"
        });
        alert(text);
    }
</script>
```

I expect the after running showMessage function, display codes changes to objective-c from javascript.
and actually error shows nothing. does anyone know how to do it ??

Answer (score 16):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but I made this little function:

```
const changeLang = lang => {
    monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(editor.getModel(), lang);
    console.log(`model language was changed to ${editor.getModel().getLanguageIdentifier().language}`);
}
```

It changes the language and prints the new model language every time for me.

Your line `editor.updateOptions({language: "objective-c"})` will not do anything. If you look at [the docs](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodelupdateoptions.html), you'll see that `ITextModelUpdateOptions` only takes `indentSize`, `insertSpaces`, `tabSize`, or `trimAutoWhitespace`.

It looks like you might have been looking at the first couple answers of [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/375) to make that line. That very first answer given is not correct.

You do `text = editor.getValue()` at the start of your function and `alert(text)` at the end, but `text` never changes. The model language will only affect the appearance, not the content. If you were only trying to get the static content, then the way you wrote it is fine. But if you were expecting it to change, it won't.

Comment: If my page has 2 monaco editor instances and I want to update language in only one of them how should I go about it, as using this - monaco.editor.setModelLanguageseems to update both.